# C++ | SFML | Иероглифы вместо кириллицы | Написать текст из переменной на русском

Tags: c++, кодировка, utf-8, sfml, ascii

Не могу вывести на экран русский текст. Просмотрел всевозможные сайты, нашел такой способ:

```
   text.setString(L"Some text");
   window.draw(text);
```

И да, **он работает**, русский текст выводится корректно.

Но все зло в том, что я беру текст из **XML** при помощи TinyXML2, т.е переношу текст в **переменную**, и уже не могу добавить **префикс L** для его работы. Пробовал способ с **wstring**, не нашел нормального объяснения, как это работает и что куда ставить, скопировал, работать не стало.

XML:

```
<root>
    <info>
        <map_name>XML файл на самом деле больше, просто тут экономлю место</map_name>
    </info>
</root>
```

C++:

```
//map_document - объект XMLDocument, которому присваивается документ XML выше
XMLNode* root = map_document->FirstChildElement("root");

XMLElement* element = root->FirstChildElement("info");

Map::map_name = element->FirstChildElement("map_name")->GetText(); //Код взят из конструктора карты
//Когда я пишу в XML английский текст, все выводится нормально, весь код выше, считайте, просто берет текст из XML <map_name>

//...Вырезано объявление текста и окна... map1 - Объект Map
sf::String test_string = map1.getMapName(); // Функция, дает map_name выше, с англ, все работает корректно
text.setString(test_string);
window.draw(text);
```

[image: Это XML with english name of map]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, что использовать, чтобы вывести русский текст (кириллица), ***!из переменной!***.

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Разберитесь с кодировками. И да, в SFML имеются готовые средства для перекодирования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ура, **7 долбанных часов спустя** (а потому что я уже 7 часов с этим вожусь)

```
string map_name = test_map.getMapName();
text.setString(String::fromUtf8(map_name.begin(), map_name.end()));
```

Решение - `sf::String::fromUtf8(youstring.begin(), youstring.end())`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ахааха, мой ответ на мой же вопрос, заданный несколько месяцев назад помог мне сейчас. О да, время большого мозга!